# How can I show a string resource in a language and store it in other?

Tags: android

I have a Spinner showing different options from a string array. The selected string will be stored into a database for later purposes.
For example, the spinner shows this items when in english (values-en):

```
<string name="none">N - None</string>
<string name="month">M - Once a month or less</string>
<string name="oweek">W - Once a week</string>
```

The user selects one and then the string is stored in a database.

The problem is when a different locale is applied. For example, in spanish (values-es) I have the following options:

```
<string name="none">N - Ninguno</string>
<string name="month">M - Una vez al mes o menos</string>
<string name="oweek">W - Una vez a la semana</string>
```

And when the user selects one, the string is stored **in spanish** into the database. I need to store them in english. Basically, the app needs to show the option "N - Ninguno" and store "N - None".

Is there any way to get the id of the selected string and store the value from other locale? Or any other solution?

Comment: you should use 'id' for every string resource. then you can store only 'id' in your database.

Comment: I need to store the actual string in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it you have two options.

- **Create another column** to save the name and the actual string.
- Have a **default language** stored in the DB.

I would go for the first one, but if you want to implement having only strings in English in the database and then check them with the current language accordingly:

To get a string from a different locale, you can use this function.

```
private String getStringLocale(int resourceId, Locale newLocale){
    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();

    //Saving Locale so we can restore it later
    Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;

    //Set new Locale depending on the parameters we are getting
    conf.locale = newLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);

    //Saving String
    String str = res.getString(resourceId);

    //Restoring original Locale
    conf.locale = savedLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);

    return str;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Log.d("LocaleSpanish", getStringLocale(R.string.app_name, new Locale("es")));
Log.d("LocaleEnglish", getStringLocale(R.string.app_name, new Locale("en")));
```